# Integrating API gateway with SAM template to have custom name and stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-sam

I am trying to have a customer name given to my API gateway created through SAM template.
and also restrict creating only one stage while deploying.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Development
      Cors: "'*'"
  GetAllUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_get_all_user
      CodeUri: code/
      Handler: get_all_user.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /get-all-user
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
```

All is working fine as I want, but

1. It is creating the API with the name of the stack (I want to give a custom name)
2. Along with the "Development" it is also adding "stage" while deploying.

[image]

How I can achieve these two cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify `Name` for your `ApiGatewayApi`, you have to use [Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-name) property:

> A name for the API Gateway RestApi resource

Thus your `ApiGatewayApi` would be:

```
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Development
      Name: MyApiName
      Cors: "'*'"
```

I'm not sure I understand the second issue, thus can't comment on it right now.

As explained [here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/191#issuecomment-580412747) you can add the following to fix the `Stage` issue:

```
Globals:
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1
```

Comment: have edited the question now, hope I am clear now

Comment: it worked :D.
don't know how do you find all these solutions especially for this one. 
Thank you once again

Comment: @sumanthshetty Your question had all details needed for the issue reproduction. So  I run the code, confirmed that it is a problem indeed,  found a possible solution, tried it to check if it works. Since it worked for me, I added it to the answer:-)

Comment: have a learn a way to find the solution as you do :D

Comment: there is one more issue that i am facing with this

Comment: @sumanthshetty You can make new question if this is something new?

Comment: here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101560/sam-package-is-ruding-the-size-of-my-template-ymal-file