# sam package is reducing the size of my template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have a SAM template that I am using to building 4 lambda functions integrated with API gateways.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.

#To avoide 'stage' being created when deploying the Api gateway.
Globals:
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1


Resources:
  # api gateway model for all user methods 
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: loadeo_user
      StageName: Development
      Cors: "'*'"

  # integrating lambda with api for loadeo_get_all_user function    
  GetAllUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_get_all_user
      CodeUri: getAllUser/
      Handler: get_all_user.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /get-all-user
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi

  # integrating lambda with api for loadeo_get_user_profile function             
  GetUserProfile:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_get_user_profile
      CodeUri: getUserProfile/
      Handler: get_user_profile.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /get-user-profile
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
#  integrating lambda with api for loadeo_update_user_profile function   
  GetUserProfile:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_update_user_profile
      CodeUri: updateUserProfile/
      Handler: update_user_profile.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /update_user_profile-user
            Method: patch
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi 


#  integrating lambda with api for loadeo_create_user function
  GetUserProfile:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_create_user
      CodeUri: createUser/
      Handler: create_all_user.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /create-user
            Method: put
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
```

the next step after this to package and deploy the code.

I am using `aws cloudformation package` as it is similar to `sam package` and I have tried both.

As soon as I run the command the template file gets reduced.
from 100 lines to 50 lines. when I observe the middle two functions are being omitted.

don't exactly know the reason for this. Is there any limit on the number of functions? or I am missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> two functions are being omitted.

The functions are skipped because they have **same name** of `GetUserProfile`. So one overwrites the other as you have three of them. You have to rename them:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.

#To avoide 'stage' being created when deploying the Api gateway.
Globals:
  Api:
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1


Resources:
  # api gateway model for all user methods 
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: loadeo_user
      StageName: Development
      Cors: "'*'"

  # integrating lambda with api for loadeo_get_all_user function    
  GetAllUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_get_all_user
      CodeUri: getAllUser/
      Handler: get_all_user.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /get-all-user
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi

  # integrating lambda with api for loadeo_get_user_profile function             
  GetUserProfile:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_get_user_profile
      CodeUri: getUserProfile/
      Handler: get_user_profile.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /get-user-profile
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
#  integrating lambda with api for loadeo_update_user_profile function   
  UpdateUserProfile:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_update_user_profile
      CodeUri: updateUserProfile/
      Handler: update_user_profile.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /update_user_profile-user
            Method: patch
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi 


#  integrating lambda with api for loadeo_create_user function
  CreateUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: loadeo_create_user
      CodeUri: createUser/
      Handler: create_all_user.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 5
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: loadeo_lambda_execution
      MemorySize: 128
      Events:
        GetAllUser:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /create-user
            Method: put
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
```

Comment: But they are get_user_profile and update_user_profile

Comment: @sumanthshetty I mean the resource names, not the function names. In your original code the resource names in SAM are same `GetUserProfile`. You have three times `GetUserProfile`.